# xammp server permalink by postname not working

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, xampp

I am able to access main page on localhost but not able to access page that I have added.it is displaying 404 error.

my question is same as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311737/permalinks-is-not-working-in-xampp-localhost-server-on-windows-7
but re-posting here as in that link no proper answer posted.

**httpd.conf SETTINGS**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

---

```
<Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

---

**HTACCESS FILE CODE**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /perms/dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /perms/dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

**mod rewrite also enabled**

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Why is your rewrite rule `RewriteRule . /perms/dev/index.php` and not `RewriteRule . /index.php`?

Comment: toscho perms/ is main directory and dev is my subdirectory

Comment: Well, yes, but you have set that as RewriteBase already.

Comment: yes, I have install fresh copy of wordpress and set permalink by %postname% and with new copy permalink working fine but not working for my existing code :(

Answer (score 1):

In `xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf`, under *Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support*, enable mod_rewrite. Uncomment the line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then restart the server, and set the permalinks in WordPress again.

Comment: mod_rewrite in already enable